# How to have 2 instances of parametrized sharedViewModel?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, koin

```kotlin
val viewModel: StuffViewModel by sharedViewModel { parametersOf(arguments.id) }
```

Now, when I have multiple instanec of the same Fragment class, how can I have new instance for each of it? I thought that's what `parametersOf()` does, but it doesn't seem to be true.

And yes, it has to be `sharedViewModel`, because of some logic which causes some complex fragment manipulation and the viewmodels are binding to services, and it seems like a better idea to just have shared instances instead of recreating them and rebinding the service every time.

What I want:

```
/---------Activity---------\
|                          |
|     StuffViewModel(1)    |
|     StuffViewModel(2)    |
|                          |
| /---StuffFragment(1)---\ |
| |                      | |
| |  *StuffViewModel(1)  | |
| |                      | |
| \----------------------/ |
|                          |
| /---StuffFragment(2)---\ |
| |                      | |
| |  *StuffViewModel(2)  | |
| |                      | |
| \----------------------/ |
|                          |
\--------------------------/
```

What I get:

```
/---------Activity---------\
|                          |
|     StuffViewModel(1)    |
|                          |
| /---StuffFragment(1)---\ |
| |                      | |
| |  *StuffViewModel(1)  | |
| |                      | |
| \----------------------/ |
|                          |
| /---StuffFragment(2)---\ |
| |                      | |
| |  *StuffViewModel(1)  | |
| |                      | |
| \----------------------/ |
|                          |
\--------------------------/
```

Comment: which kind of argument is passed to the view model? cant it be a field that can be set  after the object has been created?

Comment: Why it has to be shared view model maybe we can find a better solution.

Comment: The type is used as the key in the map. To have two separate shared ViewModel, you'd need two separate types, unless the KeyedViewModelFactory is still available (or was it ViewModelProvider.KeyedFactory?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find any toher solution then to have separate ViewModel instances.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How do you make each fragment receive its correct instance?